# Integrate playAxis in custom written bubble charts

Tags: business-intelligence, jquery-ui-slider, bubble-chart, powerview

I am using the slider for making the bubble chart in motion.
Can we Integrate Power View PlayAxis in our Bubble charts using java script.

Comment: Have you seen Highcharts plugin with slider for charts in motion? http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/40/Motion

Comment: I do'nt want to use HighChats library. Just want to Integrate it in my custom charts

Comment: So you are not using Highcharts library?

Comment: Yes. I have created my own Bubble chart